# E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitdefender.list (dist) E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: software-center

I'm getting the message

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitdefender.list (dist) E: The list of sources could not be read
```

when I try to open software centre through terminal and a red stop sign at the top of my screen.>  I know the reason for the problem, I tried installing a free bitdefender security, but don't know how to fix it and delete the malformed line, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: and the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitdefender.list`, which seems to be the problem file.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error message. I solved it just commenting (using #) the two lines from the file `bitdefender.list`. Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for `bitdefender.list` file. If it is there, do the following:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitdefender.list
```

Then, comment out the lines by inserting `#` at the beginning of each line.

Save the file and try `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal to check if the problem was solved.

Comment: while this will solve the error it will also prevent subsequent updates/upgrades from being found and installed.